# Passing dynamic param through bundle.properties to alt text value of graphicImage

Tags: jsf, parameters, bundle, graphicimage

I am trying to add a dynamic value to a string from bundle.properties, then get all of that into the alt text attribute of the graphicImage component, following the same `f:param` method used with the outputFormat component.

But it appears that does not work as expected.

*bundle.properties*

```
alt.logo={0} logo
```

*demo.xhtml*

```
<h:graphicImage value="#{result.imageUrl}" alt="#{bundle[alt.logo]}">
    <f:param value="#{result.name}"/>
</h:graphicImage>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or is there another method to achieve the same desired result?

Comment: Thank you, @Kukeltje, the OmniFaces Strings function `of:formatX()` suggested in the answer from @BalusC was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You are welcome